# Sprint Boot and Elastic Search Connection issue

Tags: java, spring, maven, elasticsearch

I'm creating an application using Spring Boot and also Elastic-Search. Spring application part is working. And also when I start Elastic server, it's also running well. No issues at all. I can test it via POSTMAN and also CURL. Adding and also searching works well.

But when I run the application, i'm getting following issues.
This is the issue i'm getting in the IDE. (which means from my java application)

> org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{127.0.0.1}{127.0.0.1:9300}]

And this is the issue i'm getting from the Elasctic server on my local system.

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]

These are the libraries I'm using.

- Spring Boot 1.5.1.RELEASE
- Spring Boot Starter Data Elasticsearch 1.5.1.RELEASE
- Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.10.RELEASE
- Elastic Search 5.0

I think this is a issue with Elastic and above library version mismatch.
I'm new to Elastic and also Spring. The version issue is here.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/wiki/Spring-Data-Elasticsearch---Spring-Boot---version-matrix

And also here is my pom.xml. If I need to update any library, can anyone tell me what's that ? And also tell me how to update those libraries ? Can I update them without changing to my source code ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0

```
<artifactId>springboot-springdata-elasticsearch-example</artifactId>
<packaging>jar</packaging>
<url>https://www.mkyong.com</url>
<version>1.0</version>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.1.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Runtime, for Embedded Elasticsearch,
        comment this if connect to external elastic search server-->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- Package as an executable jar/war -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

In this pom.xml , I can't find all the dependencies too.

Comment: According to the version matrix you linked to, you cannot use elasticsearch 5.x with the Spring libraries you want to use. Are you running elasticsearch externally? It looks like it. You need to run a 2.x of elasticsearch.

Comment: @Phil Hey what are the changes between elastic 2.x and 5.x ?

Comment: @Phil Can I update Spring libraris to use Elastic 5.x ? Please HELP me

Answer (score 1):

According to the versions matrix that you provided, the spring boot version that you're using is not compatible with ElasticSearch 5.x instances. So, i think you have 3 options:

- If you really need to work with SpringBoot 1.5.1 using ElasticSearch 5.0, you should add the maven dependencies related to ElasticSearch 5.0 and implement your own DAO service.
- You can try to downgrade your ElasticSearch version to 2.4 in order to make it compatible with your current spring boot version.
- Maybe you can try to use the recent spring boot version (1.5.4) because arcording to the spring-data-elasticsearch project (https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/), the last version supports ElasticSearch 5.x, so probably it could be the easiest way.

Please let me know if any of options above was useful for you.

Comment: Last point is so great. Actually that's what I also want. So, Can you please help me on this ?

Comment: Can I do that updating pom.xml ? Without changing my code ?

Comment: You just need to change the proyect parent version (in your pom) to 1.5.4.RELEASE (instead of 1.5.1.RELEASE): recompile your project and verify if that works.

Comment: Still having the same issue.

Comment: Received message from unsupported version: [2.0.0] minimal compatible version is: [5.0.0]  -> This is the issue.....

Comment: There are two ports like this. [o.e.t.TransportService   ] [W_slnyr] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9300}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9300}, {127.0.0.1:9300} AND [o.e.h.HttpServer         ] [W_slnyr] publish_address {127.0.0.1:9200}, bound_addresses {[::1]:9200}, {127.0.0.1:9200} ->>>> so what should i use in my application ? 9300 port..no ?

Comment: Please tell me if i need to change something else too :(

Comment: There's a chance of change ElasticSearch 5.0 to ElasticSearch 2.4?

Comment: Hmmmmm yeah still this is my development project, I have a chance

Comment: I will download it and will test it. Thanks for the help. i will keep you posted :) Network is little slow today :(

Comment: That's perfect! i had the same problem like 6 months ago and i applied the second solution, but in that time the 1.5.4 spring version did not exists, so i though that it might solve the problem :(

Comment: Is there any big changes between v5.x and v2.x ? Any considerable performance issues ?

Comment: And also I got this. "SpringBoot 1.5.1.RELEASE and Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.10.RELEASE supports only ElasticSearch 2.4.0.".. So i think we also need to update 'Spring Data Elasticsearch' dependency too. But i can't find it in my pom.xml. Do you know where i can find it ?

Comment: Yes, basically the changes are focused on indexing management. You can take a look at this page: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes-5.0.html

Comment: SpringBoot 1.5.1.RELEASE uses Spring Data Elasticsearch 2.x, so if you use ElasticSearch 2.4 it could be enough in terms of compatibility.

Comment: Done. It's working great with ES 2.X. This is nice, If i need to make it work with 5.X, i need to update 'Spring Data Elasticsearch'. U know how can i do that ? :)

Comment: The problem is that all the spring maven dependencies have a very strong relation, so...Spring Data ElasticSearch 2.4.0 works perfectly with SpringBoot 1.5.1...if you change the Spring Data ElasticSearch version to for example 2.4.1, probably you are going to have some conflicts....But if you want you can try in order to know what could happen....You only need to agregate a <version> tag in the spring elastic search data POM dependency to the latest one indicated at this page: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-elasticsearch